# Rooted Path and FileUpload Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know it's been asked and I have read the posts and Googled this all day. Still nowhere near something that works. Using an .aspx page, I need to upload a .pdf file to a specific website. I'm doing development using VS2017 and VB.Net. The app will run on different websites. It needs to upload client files to a **specific different website and path**. Also, the file name of the uploaded file will **not be the same** as the local source file. Creating the new name is no problem.

Let's say a local file must be uploaded to a website at https://www.appfileserver.co.za/pdfdocs, but I'm on https://www.myownsite.com. So, when using FileUpload1.SaveAs(*rootedpath*) the path that goes in there must be the **rooted path** to the target. What would the *rooted path* look like for the example I provided?

FYI, I know the IP addresses, http paths and anything else I need to know because I control those sites. It would be great to do an FTP upload. I have done this many times from desktop apps. Unfortunately I'd need the full path to the local file. It seems there is no way a web page is allowed to get that full path, so FTP upload is out - or is there a way?

Comment: You could upload to "myownsite.com" and then that server can upload to "otherserver.com".

Comment: Brilliant. Figured that out after making my post then tested it - with success. Doing it that way I can then do a proper FTP upload to the target path. Thanks for that.

Comment: FYI my comment above is wrong. Yes it worked on my IIS, but not on a live site. You can't FTP upload from website to website. I posted the correct solution in my answer below. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

After battling for two days trying to FTP upload from website to website (which is not possible because **server firewalls block this**), I finally solved it. The solution was a simple one. I deployed the upload .aspx file on the target server then embedded that in an ***iframe*** on the client machine apps. The files are then uploaded **one time** to the right place. Simple and 100% effective. Hopefully somebody see's this and understands it - so as to avoid the troubles I had.

Comment: The key concept here? When using web based URL's, that is a external represention of the path. But when you write code, you can 100% ignore the external path names, use mapath, and you now have a vb.net internal path name just like any code you write on your desktop computer. In fact the vb code can save the file, or get/grab/use file names anywhere on that server - these path names have quite much ZERO to do with external URL's.  it also means that the folder with pdfs does NOT have to be exposed as a valid URL that users can type in to get say other pdf's that they are not supposed to.

Comment: External URL's, and that includes often used "virtual" folders can be mapped to a specific folder. For URL's then you see folders for the web site. Once you start running code behind? Then the path names in code are full valid server path names, and have LITTLE to do with the url. Of course the translation from that external URL path to internal is done with mappath. So keep in mind the BIG difference between markup code that gets at files via the web URL (MUST use URL) as opposed to code behind that ALWAYS uses full valid windows path names. Once this distinction is made, then all makes sense